# HP Stream 11" Intel Celeron 2GB RAM32GB SSD laptop updated and is hung on shutting down. Ctrl+Alt+Del does nothing and can't find battery to remove

Tags: battery

I have an HP Stream 11" laptop with Intel Celeron, 2GB RAM, and a 32GB SSD.
When shutting down it gave options to update and shut down or sleep, so I updated. I closed the lid, and when I opened it 12 hours later the screen was hung on shutdown mode. Ctrl+Alt+Del does nothing, and I can't find battery to remove.

This has happened before and I had to wait for the power to run down.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to force shutdown a computer, when software options are not available, press and hold the power button, until it turns off. However, it should only be used in situations where you have to, because it doesn't shut Windows down properly, it cuts the power, giving the same effect as if you pulled the plug out of the wall, on a desktop PC.

Answer (score 0):

Hp Stream hard drive space is not enough to support windows upgrade anymore after you installed MS office. window 10 lite / slim doesn't work well on this machine. There are two workarounds.

1. install a small system such as Linux mint. worked well.
2. if you really want to use the windows system, you can open the case and replace the wifi card with a hard drive. and use a USB plugin wifi card.

Comment: It's good that you jumped to try and diagnose *why* the laptop was hanging. Do you have a reference for the Windows Upgrade size?

Comment: The size required seems to depend on the version of the upgrade package.  The download package was downloading in the background and slowly fill up the disc space, and it seems to require additional space to do the installing process.  I had 12G empty space to have the upgrade successfully installed. either the package or after installation took up all 12G space. but during the installing process, less than 12 G empty seems not enough in my case. hope that helps.